# Drawing to canvas

Tags: java, image, jframe, sleep

so i am dabbling in making a game and i am a fairly messy worker and then i go back and tidy it up. So please ignore any stupid naming conventions or methods or anything. As I go back later and tidy up.

So basically I am trying to make a main menu, i just want to draw something to the screen and have it stay there. I am writing the graphics to a image ATM and displaying the image as i tried just drawing to the canvas and it just flickered up onto the screen and then it went blank. I changed it to a runnable so i could put in sleep() to try and error hunt. I've removed all my error hunting code now. It turns out when i have a sleep() before or after the image is put on the screen for longer than 50ms the rectangle stays on screen and doesn't flicker away like 1ms after it was drawn.

I'm not sure what's going on. I am probably not that clear and I apologies.

```
    import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        test t = new test();
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        Graphics g;

        c.setSize(400, 400);
        f.add(c);
        f.pack();

        f.setVisible(true);
        c.setVisible(true);

        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g = c.getGraphics();

        g.drawRect(10, 10, 40, 68);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you are using AWT based components over using Swing?

Comment: Like i said forgive my noobiness, i'm rusty and wasn't particularly skilled in the first place. I'll write a runnable piece of code now...

Comment: There added in a runnable code. If you remove the sleep, you will see that the rectangle never appears...

Comment: Why are you initializing the UI from a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is not how painting in AWT works.  Painting should be done within the context of a component's `paint` method.  In AWT `Canvas` seems to be the preferred base component to use.

You should never use `getGraphics`, apart from been able to return `null`, it will only represent the `Graphics` context from the last paint cycle, anything added to it could be wiped about by newer paint events...which is probably happening to you.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting works.

Having said all that, I would discourage you from using AWT based API as it was replaced by Swing some 15 years ago.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting in Swing

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of getting the idea, but there are a few standard design patterns of creating a game, for starters [check out this code](https://github.com/freefouran/gow/blob/master/src/io/gow/Bootstrap.java).

Basically, you'll need something called a game loop which will update and render to the display a certain amount of times every second (framerate or fps). When it renders, it will clear and redraw the image in a new location at a certain interval, if your fps was 60 you would be rendering (clearing, and redrawing) 60 times a second. We can also introduce more advanced concepts such as buffer strategies (shown in the example above) to reduce tearing and flickering.

To sum it up, you're kind of there, you just need to constantly do that `g = c.getGraphics()` so...

```
while (true) {
     g = c.getGraphics();

     // set color
     // draw a rectangle

     g.dispose();
}
```

Note how I added the dispose, this will just free up any unused memory. Just to clarify, this is by no means good code, but it will give you a place to start :)

The flickering is due to only having 1 screen, to stop this flickering you need a [buffer strategy](https://github.com/freefouran/gow/blob/master/src/io/gow/Bootstrap.java#L25). Basically having two buffers is like having two screens, whilst you render on one 'screen' you can clear and draw the next step on the second screen and switch between the two buffers; this reduces the flickering.